# Good Windows Registry Wrapper for C++

Tags: c++, wrapper, registry

Does anyone know of any good free/open source Windows Registry wrappers for VC++ which do not require MFC (i.e. can be run in a console app)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ATL comes with a basic [CRegKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xka57xy4(VS.80).aspx) wrapper that might suit your needs and is easy to use from a console application.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote one a long time ago and put it on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/cregistrykey.aspx); it's comprehensive but I'd do things a bit differently these days.