# How can save Application Settings in the Registry via MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc, registry

I have a MFC application created by the MFC Project Wizard. I wanted to save/read application settings in the registry and so asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880275/good-c-registry-wrapper) to find a C++ Registry wrapper as the Windows API is very messy. However, I have now heard that the MFC provides a way to do this. Is this true? If so, how can I read/write values, see whether a key exists and get a list of all the keys?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MFC provides an easy way to read/write Windows registry.

In your project you'll have a global `CMyProjectName theApp;` object.
`CMyProjectName` inherits `CWinApp` class which provides the [SetRegistryKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c2w6z4k%28VS.80%29.aspx) method.
That method sets `theApp` to write in the registry instead of an "ini" file.

In the documentation check out

```
CWinApp::GetProfileInt
CWinApp::GetProfileString
CWinApp::WriteProfileInt
CWinApp::WriteProfileString
```

methods on how to read and write integers and strings in the registry.