# Try to Save user the input MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

How can I save the text that the user enters in a IPAddress Control so that the next time it opens the app it will be kept?What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [CIPAddressCtrl::GetAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8343d9w1(v=vs.90).aspx) to retrieve address given in control.
- Use [CIPAddressCtrl::SetAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3x1d9y3s(v=vs.90).aspx) to set address into control.

**EDIT**

You may use something like:

```
HKEY hkey; 
CString strIP ="127.0.0.1"; 

if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"Software\\YourApp",0,KEY_WRITE,&hkey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
   RegSetValueEx(hkey,"IPAddress",0,REG_SZ,(unsigned char*)strIP .GetBuffer(0),strIP .GetLength());
   RegCloseKey(hkey); 
}
```

Comment: Hey, that's not what I asked.I'm trying to keep what they have typed so that the next time he opens the app that he won't have to type it again,thanks!

Comment: You can use registry, own external file, database... that depends on you.

Comment: How can I do it with registry?

Answer (score 0):

for example you can save the IP adress in a file on your drive :

```
void CIPAdressDialogDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    // TODO : ajoutez ici le code de votre gestionnaire de notification de contrôle
    // OnOK();
    BYTE field0, field1, field2, field3;
    m_Ip.GetAddress(field0, field1, field2, field3);

    CString strIp = _T("");
    strIp.Format(_T("%u.%u.%u.%u"), field0, field1, field2, field3);

    CString strFilePath = _T("C:\\test.txt");

    CFile theFile(strFilePath, CFile::modeWrite | CFile::modeCreate);
    theFile.Write(strIp, strIp.GetLength() * sizeof(TCHAR));
}
```

Comment: There is no need to store IP Address in string format unless absolutely necessary (specially if binary file is used).

Comment: Thanks! and if I want to save it in the registry?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882161/how-can-save-application-settings-in-the-registry-via-mfc