# How to get MRU List data?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, registry

how can i get data prgogrammaticaly from windows registry MRU list? I am using vc++. For example windows xp search history is located in Software\Microsoft\Search Assistant\ACMru\5603. How can i get data from it?

EDIT:I still dont know howto do this, can you be more specific? So what steps do i need to do to have acess to data?

Comment: Which MRU list do you mean? Run? documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the Run MRU have a look at:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU`

Document MRU is saved on filesystem as .lnk-files. Under Windows 7 it is:

`%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent`

*Edit:*

On this XP Machine I've got only one entry under the key

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Search Assistant\ACMru\5603`

It is

`Name=000, Type=REG_SZ, Value="*.tmp"`

I suppose that means that on this machine Search has only been used once, more precisely it is the first (and only) entry in the MRU list, so next entry showing up would be:

`Name=001, Type=REG_SZ, Value=...` and so on.

If your question is now how to access the Windows registry, have a look here:

[Good Windows Registry Wrapper for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880275/good-windows-registry-wrapper-for-c)

or for the plain api here:

http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Windows-Scripting/Working-with-the-Windows-Registry-in-C-plus-plus/

Comment: I am interesting in getting windows search history, so programmaricaly. Do i only need to open file and read it?

Comment: What does the data look like?

Comment: i dont know how they look like, i dont know where they can be foun, i only know that when i delete a registry key, the history is gone :D

Comment: I will check the key when I am on a Windows XP machine tomorrow. It seems that Win 7 uses a different key (since it uses Windows Search...)